# What is the smallest amount of code needed to use a wasm array

Tags: javascript, arrays, webassembly

I have a c++ file that contains a function which does nothing but math.

This function takes in an array as an argument and saves all it's results back into the same array.

I can compile this with emscripten, and that would give me a working js and wasm file but the javascript it generates is filled with tons of fillers I don't need.

If I wasn't trying to pass in an array I would do the below:

```
var bytes = .... // The bytes of the wasm file
var Module = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(Module);
var desiredFunction = instance.exports.desiredFunction;
```

However when I use the first 3 lines of code above to initialize wasm and then I try to call this command:

```
var buffer = Module._malloc(array.length);  //setup space in wasm memory
```

I get an error saying "Module._malloc" is not a function. What more code do I need to write to get malloc ccwrap and ccall to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Emscripten was not designed for compiling very small programs. It was designed for compiling large codebases - as a result it automatically bundles all sorts of things into the generated wasm and hosting JS file.

There is an [issue that discusses adding this as a feature](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/5794) - i.e. the ability to create a minimal JS host.

There are other, more lightweight, tools for compiling C / C++ - such as [webassembly](https://github.com/dcodeIO/webassembly) - which might be more appropriate for your needs.